# Использовать https:// вместо git:// в терминале linux

Tags: terminal, git, ruby-on-rails, github, linux

Есть сеть с выходом наружу через прокси с авторизацией.
Есть Fedora 20 Security с xfce4-terminal. В переменных среды описаны `http\_proxy`, `ftp\_proxy`, `https\_proxy`. И даже для возможных извращенцев прописал `git\_proxy`. Также:

```
[dan@crystal ~]$ git --version
git version 1.9.3
[dan@crystal ~]$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [i686-linux]
[dan@crystal ~]$ gem -v
2.2.2
[dan@crystal ~]$ rails -v
Rails 4.1.6
```

При ручном использовании git'a я могу заменить, например:

```
git clone 'git://github.com/maccman/gdata.git' "foobar" --bare --no-hardlinks
```

на

```
git clone 'https://github.com/maccman/gdata.git' "foobar" --bare --no-hardlinks
```

И всё будет работать. Но при развертывании rails приложения автоматически используется протокол git, как в первом варианте. А это не проходит через прокси.

Можно ли где-то в системе глобально обозначить использование https вместо git?

P.S. Не помогло

```
git config --global http.proxy http://<name>:<pass>@<proxy>:<port>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почитайте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11383587/887325), мне кажется, это решение вашего вопроса.

Продублирую на всякий случай:

```
git config --global url.https://.insteadOf git://
```

P.S. Сам не тестил, отпишитесь, если помогло.

Comment: Да, спасибо большое, это помогло!

Answer (score 0):

На второй машине пошел другим путем, пустив ssh через прокси.
Так тоже всё работает.